# Python String method Obscured

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to split a string returned from the Python implementation of Interactive Broker's API, but I keep getting a:

```
AttributeError: 'TickPrice' object has no attribute 'split'

def my_price_handler(msg):
    fields=msg.split()
    print fields[0]
```

Checked the API code and (1) msg is a string and (2) 'split' is not redefined elsewhere.  Msg string looks like this `<Tick Price tickerId=1, field=1, price=74.0, canAutoExecute=1>` and can be printed to console directly.  Same error message when using syntax:

```
def my_price_handler(msg):
    fields=string.split(msg)
    print fields[0]
```

I have imported string at the top of the program.

Is this a variable scope issue?

Comment: Did you check whether `isinstance(msg, basestring)` or `type(msg) in [str, unicode]`? What you have pasted as value of `msg` could very well be a `__str__` representation of a class (the `TickPrice` mentioned in error message, most likely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, `msg` is *not* a string when it enters `my_price_handler`; it's a `TickPrice`. Put

```
print(type(msg))
```

before the `split` call to convince yourself of this fact.

(The fact that `msg` can be printed does not mean it's a string, if that's what you thought.)

Answer (score 1):

TickPrice appears to be a Class.  msg is an Instance of said class, which has a `__repr__` method which allows you to `print` it to the console, producing:

```
<Tick Price tickerId=1, field=1, price=74.0, canAutoExecute=1>
```